# Retrieve cells with a specific formatting from other sheets into a new sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I have a several sheets containing different data of interest. I have highlighted the cells with a specific colour, and it will be helpful to have it shown in a "consolidated" sheet that will fetch the highlighted data from anywhere in the other sheet as long as it has the highlighting.

I would like to show the green interesting cells from sheet2, sheet 3, sheet 4, into column A of Sheet1, based on that specific colour. NB. contents is different, the screenshot is just an example.

[image: I would like to show the green interesting cells from sheet2, sheet 3, sheet 4, into column A of Sheet1, based on that specific colour.]

I am a bit confused as if I should use conditional formatting, VLOOKUP, IF, or a mix of all, and I am a bit lost with this.

Comment: I think you'd need to use `VBA` for this I'm afraid.

Comment: Mhh, that would be too difficult for me to pick up quickly enough (and I wouldn't know where to look for it) to have it mastered and solved the problem vs. doing it manually. I am totally against being turned into a computer slave, but technology failed me. Thanks for your answer anyway,